# ElasticSearch and NEST - How do I construct a simple OR query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm developing a building repository query.

Here is the query that I am trying to write.

> (Exact match on `zipCode`) AND ((Case-insensitive exact
>   match on `address1`) OR (Case-insensitive exact match on `siteName`))

In my repository, I have a document that looks like the following:

> `address1`: 4 Myrtle Street
>   `siteName`: Myrtle Street
>   `zipCode`: 90210

And I keep getting matches on:

> `address1`: 4**5** Myrtle Street
>   `siteName`: Myrtle
>   `zipCode`: 90210

Here are some attempts that have not worked:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "address1": {
                    "value": "45 myrtle street"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "siteName": {
                    "value": "myrtle"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "zipCode": {
              "value": "90210"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "zipCode": {
            "value": "90210"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "address1": "45 myrtle street"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "siteName": "myrtle"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




{
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "or": {
            "filters": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "address1": "45 myrtle street"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "siteName": "myrtle"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "zipCode": "90210"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}




{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "span_or": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_term": {
                  "siteName": {
                    "value": "myrtle"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "zipCode": {
              "value": "90210"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}



{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "zipCode": {
            "value": "90210"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "or": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "address1": "45 myrtle street"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "siteName": "myrtle"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I'm writing this with NEST, so I would prefer NEST syntax, but ElasticSearch syntax would certainly suffice as well.

**EDIT:** Per @Greg Marzouka's comment, here are the mappings:

```
{
   [indexname]: {
      "mappings": {
         "[indexname]elasticsearchresponse": {
            "properties": {
               "address": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "address1": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "address2": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "address3": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "city": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "country": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "originalSourceId": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "placeId": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "siteName": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "siteType": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "state": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "systemId": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "zipCode": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check elasticsearch config, it is include lowercase filter index?

Comment: @huwence: My problem is that my queries are matching on criteria that it shouldn't.

Comment: The first query looks good.  I suspect the problem is with how your fields are being analyzed, particularly `siteName`.  Mind doing a `GET /your-index-name/_mapping?pretty` and sharing the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your mapping, you won't be able to search for exact matches on `siteName` because it's being analyzed with the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer), which is more tuned for full text search.  This is the default analyzer that is applied by Elasticsearch when one isn't explicitly defined on a field.

The standard analyzer is breaking up the value of `siteName` into multiple tokens.  For example, `Myrtle Street` is tokenized and stored as two separate terms in your index, `myrtle` and `street`, which is why your query is matching that document.  For a case-insensitive exact match, instead you want `Myrtle Street` stored as a single, lower-cased token in your index: `myrtle street`.

You could set `siteName` to `not_analyzed`, which won't subject the field to the analysis chain at all- meaning the values will not be modified.  However, this will produce a single `Myrtle Street` token, which will work for exact matches, but will be case-sensitive.

What you need to do is create a custom analyzer using the keyword tokenizer and lowercase token filter, then apply it to your field.

Here's how you can accomplish this with NEST's fluent API:

```
// Create the custom analyzer using the keyword tokenizer and lowercase token filter
var myAnalyzer = new CustomAnalyzer
{
    Tokenizer = "keyword",
    Filter = new [] { "lowercase" }
};

var response = this.Client.CreateIndex("your-index-name", c => c
    // Add the customer analyzer to your index settings
    .Analysis(an => an
        .Analyzers(az => az
            .Add("my_analyzer", myAnalyzer)
        )
    )
    // Create the mapping for your type and apply "my_analyzer" to the siteName field
    .AddMapping<YourType>(m => m
        .MapFromAttributes()
        .Properties(ps => ps
            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.SiteName).Analyzer("my_analyzer"))
        )
    )
);
```